# Identify the index of something in Python 3

Tags: python, string, indexing

I'm new to python, and I'm wondering if there is a way to identify the index position of something in python?

For example, if I have a string consisting of the alphabet a-z, and I ask the user to input a letter, is there a way I can make the program identify that the letter "f" has the index 5 in the alphabet string?

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean like this?

```
alpha = "abcdefghijkl..."
alpha.index("f")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> 'asdfsadg'.index('f')
3
```

Comment: Are you considered about strings with multiple occurrences of the letter, like the word "office"? Note that the index method will always return the index of the *first* occurrence.